# Reactjs Sort By Price

Tags: reactjs

I want to sort my product after I click the text "Sort by Log To High",
I put "product.sort((a,b) => a.productPrice > b.productPrice ? 1 : -1)" in a onClick function but it does not work. Now it works only if I put in the const displayProduct.
Any tutorial or video may I refer to? Thanks for helping.

[image: Default Display Data]

```
export const Product = () =>{
const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0)

const productPerPage = 12
const pagesVisited = pageNumber * productPerPage

const displayProduct = product
.slice(pagesVisited,pagesVisited + productPerPage)
.map(product => {
    return(
        <div className='imageContainer ' key={product.id}>
            <img src={PopularOne} className="image"/>
            <div className='productName'>
            <Link style={{ textDecoration:'none' }} to="/productsDetails" state={{ product:product }}>{product.productName}</Link>
            </div>
            <div className='productPrice'>
            <h3 >RM{product.productPrice}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>   
    )
})

    //product.sort((a,b) => a.productPrice > b.productPrice ? 1 : -1)
    



const pageCount = Math.ceil(product.length/ productPerPage)

const changePage = ({selected}) =>{
    setPageNumber(selected)
}


useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/routes/getProduct`); 
          console.log(res)
          setProduct(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);



  
return(
    <div className='product'>
       

            <div>
                <button><h3>Sort By Low to High</h3></button>
                <h3>Sort By High to Low</h3>
            </div>

            <div className='productContainer'>
                    {displayProduct}
            </div>
            <ReactPaginate
                previousLabel={""}
                nextLabel={""}
                breakLabel="..."
                pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                pageCount={pageCount}
                onPageChange={changePage}
                containerClassName={"pagination"}
                breakClassName={"break"}
                pageClassName={"page-item"} //li
                pageLinkClassName={"page-link"} //a
                activeLinkClassName={"page-link-active"}
                />  
        <Footer/>
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question to post code as text, and remove the images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the [`useState`](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState#examples-basic) function provided by React it returns 2 things, first is the state variable, and second is the updater function. In your case the state is `product` and the updater is `setProduct`.

It doesn't work because you are trying to modify the state variable, just use the updater function, and it will work.

For example:

```js
setProduct(prevState => {
    let newState = [...prevState];
    newState.sort((a, b) => a.productPrice > b.productPrice ? 1 : -1);
    return newState;
});
```

1. Updater function provides the previous state, in this case it's named `prevState`.
2. Shallow clone the array and store it in the `newState`
   variable.
3. Mutate the `newState` array via the `sort` method.
4. Return the `newState`. By returning here we tell React to update the state to the value of `newState`.